# How to not display the count column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, group-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        COUNT(STATUS)
FROM    tablename
WHERE   STATUS = 'GREEN'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(STATUS) > 3;
```

I need the results to display exclusively the ID column without the counts for each row.

Comment: just remove `count(STATUS)` from `select`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove it from the select list:

```
select   ID -- count(STATUS) removed here
from     TABLENAME
where    STATUS = 'GREEN' 
group by ID
having   count(STATUS) > 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wrapper query:

```
SELECT sub.ID FROM (
SELECT  ID ,
        COUNT(STATUS)
FROM    tablename
WHERE   STATUS = 'GREEN'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(STATUS) > 3) AS sub;
```

Comment: Wow that is a complicated way to get there.

Comment: This helped me with a different problem, where I needed the ID of a query without the having!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     ID
     --,COUNT(STATUS) as [Count]
FROM    tablename
WHERE   STATUS = 'GREEN'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(STATUS) > 3;
```

I would also add " as [Count]" when displaying that column to add a label to the column.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL (SSMS)

```
SELECT ID  --,COUNT(STATUS) as [Status Count]
FROM    tablename
WHERE   STATUS = 'GREEN'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(STATUS) > 3;
```

Subqueries as posted above can come in handy for complicated queries
or
You can also use CTE - Common Table Expressions,
Like

```
with Status_count as 
(
SELECT ID, COUNT(STATUS) as [Status Count]
FROM    tablename
WHERE   STATUS = 'GREEN'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(STATUS) > 3
)
select ID
from Status_count
```

CTE's are used for simplifying the problems and covert them to subqueries, If possible.

Comment: I am new to using StackOverflow. Please guide me if my syntax or I post something not upto standards.

Thanks

Comment: Do give a thumbs up or upvote, if I was of any help.